# $scope.$apply() in angular working but throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I put the isolated example together in a jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/deqerelita/1/

**Scenario**
Basically the idea is simple. Click a button, the controller adds to the model, the view gets updated accordingly with a hidden input type="file". After the view is updated, the controller clicks the last file input added.

**Problem**
When the controller clicks the file input before running $scope.$apply() nothing happens till the second click, presumably because angular has not registered the new input yet.
When I run $scope.$apply() the console throws errors but does click the input.

**Here is the html:**

```
  <div ng-controller="fileButtons">
    <input type="button" ng-click="handleImage.add()" value="add another file button"/>

    <div class="imageUploadPreviewContainer">
        <div class="imageUploadPreview hide" data-ng-repeat="file in files" file-index="{{$index}}">
            <input type="file" class="hide"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div></div>
```

**Here is the angular js:**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('fileButtons', ['$scope', '$log',
    function($scope, $log){
        $scope.files = [];
        $scope.handleImage = {
            add: function(){
              $scope.files.push({
                state : 'started'
              });
              $log.log('added');
              $scope.$apply(); 
              angular.element('.imageUploadPreviewContainer .imageUploadPreview:last input[type=file]').trigger('click')
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Completely new to angular so pardon any noooobish design flaws

Comment: so when you click the button the first time, an open file dialog should appear?..and its not appearing without using $apply? Am I understanding that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `$timeout`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('fileButtons', ['$scope', '$log','$timeout', function($scope, $log, $timeout)
{
    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.handleImage = {
      add: function()
      {
        $scope.files.push({state : 'started'});
        $log.log('added');
        $timeout(function()
        {
          angular.element('.imageUploadPreviewContainer .imageUploadPreview:last input[type=file]').trigger('click')
        },0);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: There is no need in 100ms timeout.

Comment: Ahhh... i did not know about the angular custom setTimeout function. I was trying this with the vanilla timeout but it did nothing. Thanks, this has worked.

Comment: yeah man, I had the same issue when I started with angular. Using vanilla js still, I often find myself trying to use `$timeout`

Comment: :)  ta very much. I think i must have tried a million variations of trying to get this thing to work haha

Answer (score 1):

As `$scope.$apply()` trigger a `$digest` and in angular at any point in time there can be only one `$digest` or `$apply` operation in progress.

You should use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
 $timeout(function(){
   angular.element('.imageUploadPreviewContainer .imageUploadPreview:last input[type=file]').trigger('click')
 }, 0)
```

Note: You should inject $timeout in your controller.